# What is a pseudo-merge join?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

This is the description from [Microsoft TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13105.trace-flags-in-sql-server.aspx) explaining Trace Flag 342 (emphasis added):

> Disables the costing of **pseudo-merge joins**, thus significantly
>   reducing time spent on the parse for certain types of large,
>   multi-table joins. One can also use SET FORCEPLAN ON to disable the
>   costing of pseudo-merge joins because the query is forced to use the
>   order specified in the FROM clause.

Does any of you know what is a pseudo-merge join? As far as I know, SQL Server has 3 Join Algorithms (Nest Loop Join, Merge Join, and Hash Join - which encompass Bitmap Join). So what is a pseudo-merge join, and what is the difference between it and a regular Merge Join or any other join for that matter?

Comment: Would be interesting to know what date this flag originates from. Maybe some ancient thing that's no longer relevant. This repository of trace flags https://sqlcrossjoin.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/sqlcrossjoin_traceflagrepository_v5.pdf points to http://smallbusiness.support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/169630 but that page doesn't seem to exist anymore (or doesn't show for me, I get redirected to the GB site)

Comment: @MartinSmith Nice find. Here's that linked KB article: [BUG: 6.5 Parse/Compile Time Is Greater than 6.0 on Large Join](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/169630)

Comment: @TimLehner nice find yourself! I did Google but didn't find that. Proper merge joins weren't introduced until SQL Server 7 AFAIK. I'm not sure what that 6.5 functionality was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a kind of old question but I will try to answer it as specific as I can.

Pseudo-merge is not a type of Join used as a T-SQL language operator, my interpretation of Microsoft's [explanation](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13105.trace-flags-in-sql-server.aspx) that using the **Trace Flag 342** is as folows:

> Disables the costing of pseudo-merge joins, thus significantly
>   reducing time spent on the parse for certain types of large,
>   multi-table joins.

Pseudo-merge is the concept to represent that the query optimiser is trying to calculate a better query execution plan, trying to obtain the best way to join the several tables.

> One can also use SET FORCEPLAN ON to disable the costing of
>   pseudo-merge joins because the query is forced to use the order
>   specified in the FROM clause.

This option [prevents the optimizer from trying to calculate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188344.aspx) and simply execute the joins as they are listed in the query.

An article on [SET FORCEPLAN ON](https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/sql-server-set-forceplan-set-statement-join-hints/) for reference.

Comment: I like your answer, and according to intense Google, I could not find any mention of a pseudo-merge join (other than the Trace Flag 342), so I guess your interpretation is most likely the right one.